# What is the fastest way to clear cache and cookies in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, cookies, browser-cache

The [standard way](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582) (hamburger icon>Tools>Clear browsing data>Confirm) is slow, especially when you have to clear frequently during development. Currently, I hit F12 to bring up the Console, go to the network tab, and right click Clear cache, right click Clear cookies.

I have also tried extensions such as [Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en), but haven't found one I love.

Is there a faster way? One click for example?

Comment: Not the fastest way, but just a good thing to know: if the dev tools are open, you can clear the cache and refresh the page by right clicking the refresh icon and clicking "empty cache and hard reload"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm on Mac and this is the shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

On Windows, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

This link gives you all shortcuts for Chrome: [Chrome Support: Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165450)

Answer (score 4):

I use the Chrome extension [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn). It does the same as Chrome's own Clear Browsing Data dialogue, but you can assign a short cut (or just use the extension button next to the address bar) to it. I have mine set up to reload the page and remove any cache from the last hour by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. It saves me a lot of time, not having to enter Chrome's dialogue, when editing a web site.

Comment: Are there any extensions that don't require "read and change all data on websites you visit"?

Comment: Must say I doubt that, since cache is data on the sites you visit. So I'm guessing those permission is a requirement. I've done no research though.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't apply to the cookies, in the F12 Developer Tools setting, you can choose to disable cache while the Developer Tools is open.

Open Developer Tools and select the settings button in the top right corner.  On the General page you can check the box.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is built right into chrome. You don't need any extensions. 
If you bring up the developer console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and press and hold the reload button you see a list of options.

- Normal reload <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Hard reload <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Empty cache and hard reload

So what you're looking for is the second one. Fastest shortcut.

Relevant question: [What's the difference between “Normal Reload”, “Hard Reload”, and “Empty Cache and Hard Reload” in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969315/whats-the-difference-between-normal-reload-hard-reload-and-empty-cache-a)

Comment: This doesn't clear the cookies, I just tried it :(

Comment: I also tried this on mac, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Not the fastest but similar to the F12 method and more user friendly:

- Click in the "lock" symbol to the left of the url bar
- "Cookies"
- Select domain to delete (or single cookies) and "Remove" button
- repeat for each domain :s

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Cookie, LocalStorage or other session related data issues use an **Incognito** window every time you start.

If you want to start it from your IDE:

```
chrome.exe -incognito
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: It's not a direct answer but it's a solution to prevent the need to clear the cache frequently during development.